Schengen visa (Indian passport) for Cruise Ship - Italy or Greece?
We're planning a trip that starts with us spending 3 days in Athens and then we are planning to take a cruise from Rome Italy (returns to the same port) for 13 days. However, all the ports we'd be visiting are in Greece, Italy, Turkey and Cyprus.
We're applying for a Schengen visa from India. We are unsure whether to apply for it through the Greek or Italian Consulate?
Does the cruise count as all Italy days since the cruise is starting and ending there or does my total number of days that are in Greece (land and sea) take precedence over it since combined they will be more?
The general guideline is to apply through the country where you spend most days, right? But what about cruises and sea days?

Note that given you're visiting Turkey, you'll need a multi-entry Schengen visa as you'll be leaving the Schengen area and returning.


The general guideline is to apply through the country where you spend most days, right?

Yes, but if that cannot be determined, then the fallback solution is to choose the first country you entered.
This would then be Greece.

(c) if no main destination can be determined, the Member State whose external border the applicant intends to cross in order to enter the territory of the Member States.


And the OP says "total number of days that are in Greece (land and sea) ... combined will be more."

@WeatherVane The trip will also be leaving the Schengen Area (Türkiye and Cyprus) for an unknown amount of days. So based on what is known, the main destination cannot be determined.

@MarkJohnson slightly relevant: Having a valid schengen visa (unless you hold a turkish passport) also lets you enter Cyprus. Timatic, paranthesis by me for brewity: "Passengers with a double or multiple entry "C" visa (or "D" visa, or residence permit) issued by Bulgaria, Romania or a Schengen Member State valid for the period of intended stay. They are visa exempt for a maximum stay of 90 days. "

So i can apply via Greece and request for a multiple entry, right? @WeatherVane

Moreover, if we are granted a multiple entry we can get a Turkish e-visa on the basis of it. Also, visit Cyprus under the same rule.

Are visias needed for a cruise shop stop in Turkey?
